# Request working from Postman but resetting from Axios in the command line

Tags: javascript, http, postman, axios

I'm having an odd issue. I'm testing an API and I sketched my requests out in Postman. In fact, they are currently working perfectly there.

```
POST /authEndpoint
content-type: application/json
accept: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
postman-token: some-token
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.1.1
host: greatapi.com
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 68
{
 "user": "user",
 "password": "secret"
}
```

I get my desired response. Now I tried to recreate this request using Axios in JavaScript. The issue is that instead of the response I get a read ECONNRESET. I believe I sketched it out just like in Postman, so it's odd. Here's my Axios config:

```
import AXIOS from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = 'https://greatapi.com';

const axios = AXIOS.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  }
});

axios.post('/authEndpoint', {
  'user': 'user',
  'password': 'secret',
})
  .then(response => console.log(response.data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error.message));
```

The specific response is this:

```
read ECONNRESET
```

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be an issue with a corporate firewall. I could fix it by using the *https-proxy-agent* package and setting the agent on Axios to it, passing my corporate proxy.

```
const axios = AXIOS.create({
  ...
  httpsAgent: new HttpsProxyAgent('http://127.0.0.1:3128'),
  proxy: false,
  ...
});
```